# How to create a blank/empty column with SELECT query in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to generate an output with blank/empty column with a "Select" query in oracle. I'm able to achieve this with below sql query:

```
SELECT CustomerName AS Customer, "" AS Contact 
FROM Customers;
```

So when I run above sql query it returns a table with two columns "Customer" column with content in it and "Contact" column with no content or blank column.
I want to achieve same with oracle query. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do mean by "Oracle query"? Especially as distinct from "SQL Query"? My guess is you mean SQL as implemented in SQL Server and SQL as implemented in Oracle Database Server. Also, in Oracle strings are delimited with single quotes. So `"" AS Contact` would be `'' AS Contact` Note also, in Oracle, `NULL` and the empty string `''` are the same thing.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance: I'm new to this database queries, so I'm sorry if I have confused you with my terminology. However your guess is correct. Also I tried `'' AS Contact` as you suggested in sql developer tool but I is generating (null) in each row of Contact column. My requirement is to generate blank/empty rows in Contact column. FYI, if I run `"" AS Contact` query on H2 database it is generating blank/empty rows. Actually my requirement is to convert already existing sql query on H2 database to Oracle database.

Answer (score 55):

I think you should use null

```
SELECT CustomerName AS Customer, null AS Contact 
FROM Customers;
```

And Remember that Oracle

> treats a character value with a length of zero as null.

Comment: I tried this query in sql developer tool, it is generating Contact column with (null) in every row. But my requirement is it should generate blank/empty rows in Contact column. Where as the same query when I run in SQuirrel tool running on H2 data base it generates blank/empty Contact column. I want to get same result when I run a query on oracle database.

Comment: I don't undetsand  .. update your question with  proper data sample

Comment: I have fixed my issue with below query:                                                           `SELECT CustomerName Customer, NVL('',' ') Contact FROM Customers `. Here it is replacing the null values with empty space.

Comment: Well  ..so you needed that in the field there is a value, but it is not visible?  I did not understand the question

Comment: There is a value as "Null" and I want it to be empty. So I just replacing this null value with empty space (' ').

Comment: @user3878988   Remeber that  Oracle internally changes empty string to NULL values. Oracle simply won't let insert an empty string.https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements005.htm .. see the note .. i have added this to the answer  too ..

Comment: [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941856/how-to-declare-null-column-in-sql-oracle-in-select-statement) is helpful. You should cast the null to a varchar (or whatever data type you want)

Answer (score 13):

In DB2, using single quotes instead of your double quotes will work. So that could translate the same in Oracle..

```
SELECT CustomerName AS Customer, '' AS Contact 
FROM Customers;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will get ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier if you use the following

```
SELECT "" AS Contact  FROM Customers;
```

And if you use the following 2 statements, you will be getting the same null value populated in the column.

```
SELECT '' AS Contact FROM Customers; OR SELECT null AS Contact FROM Customers;
```