# How to declare null column in SQL oracle in Select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I'm trying to create a NULL column in the SELECT statement but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT mytable. *, NULL as ColumnName
FROM mytable;
```

The error code is

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01723: zero-length columns are not allowed
01723. 00000 -  "zero-length columns are not allowed"
*Cause:    Columns with zero length were not allowed.
*Action:   Correct the use of the column.
```

So it seems like it's not possible to do that. Is there any choice to create a NULL column in the SELECT statement?

Thank you,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can `cast()` `NULL` to whatever type you want:

```
SELECT t.*, CAST(NULL as VARCHAR2(100)) as ColumnName
FROM mytable t;
```

Note:  Your code should work just as a `SELECT`.  The issue comes if you are trying to save the data.