# How to force an empty field in SELECT query to be of certain data type?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I would like to add an empty field to the select query, but I want to choose the data type for it.

Here, the blank field `BirthDay` will be string/varchar

```
SELECT CustomerName AS Customer, "" AS BirthDay FROM Customers;
```

but I would like to achieve, that this field will be `Date` data type.

this question extends the post here: [How to create a blank/empty column with SELECT query in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38730089/how-to-create-a-blank-empty-column-with-select-query-in-oracle/38730128)

Thanks

Comment: Note, _column_, not field.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cast()`:

```
select cast(NULL as date)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CustomerName AS Customer, cast(NULL as date) AS BirthDay FROM Customers;
```

Comment: If any of the answers helped you please accept it. So that, the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

All roads lead to Rome...

- `SELECT DATE(NULL)`
- `SELECT CONVERT(NULL, DATE)`
- `SELECT CAST(NULL as DATE)`